# Conda installation failed on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda

Conda installation failing on WSL Ubuntu 22.04 because of following:

> anaconda.sh: line 353: bunzip2: command not found

Couldn't find bunzip2 package:

`sudo apt-get install bunzip2` gives

> E: Unable to locate package bunzip2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sudo apt-get install bzip2`.
There’s no `bunzip2` package I think. The person writing the error message in Conda gave it a full name but the real name is `bzip2`.

If you search both names in the address below, you’ll see what I say about the naming:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bzip2&searchon=names

Comment: `bunzip2` is an alias for `bzip2 -d` that the `bzip2` package provides. There is no *"...person writing the error message in Conda..."*, rather `bunzip2` was called and not found by the system - that's how the shell shows errors.